# Need to display text when button clicked

Tags: angular, web-applications, frontend

I am working first angular js stuff dont know where I am making mistake but below is the code I am trying but not working.

```
I have tried to run the code it does render the html elements but doesn't do anthing.

<code>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of sampleData[0]"> {{ data.username }} </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textInput">
<button (click)="onClick(textInput)">Click me!</button>

<p>{{ displayValue }}</p>

</code>
```

Git url : https://github.com/Ramesh5688/angularTask

Comment: where do you want to display and what

Comment: when I enter in the textbox it should display in any tag like <p> or <h1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's too simple, just bind the **`ngModel`** variable to wherever you want to show

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textInput">
<button (click)="displayValue=textInput">Click me!</button>
<p>{{ displayValue }}</p>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whjguq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display value which you are entering in your input field then you can directly bind that **ngModel** variable.

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of sampleData[0]"> {{ data.username }} </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textInput">
<button>Click me!</button>

<p>{{textInput}}</p>
```

It will be good practice if you didn't use `sampleData[0]`.Use `sampleData` as I had defined below.
If you want to display value only on button click then you can check following code:

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of sampleData"> {{ data.username }} </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textInput">
<button (click)="onClick()">Click me!</button>

<p>{{ displayValue }}</p>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sampleData:any;
  textInput = '';
  displayValue: string;

  constructor (private _jsonService: JsonServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._jsonService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.sampleData = data;
    });
  }

  onClick() {
    this.displayValue = this.textInput;
  }
}
```